# Connection refused in sftp server

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, libssh2

I am trying to use localhost as SFTP server. I'm using Jsch library of Java to implement SFTP with SSH2. The following code upload a text file to a directory on local machine with sftp.
But I cannot connect to localhost.

```
        import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
        import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.OutputStream;


        import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
        import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
        import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
        import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;


        public class  Server{

        public Server() {
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String SFTPHOST = "localhost";
        int    SFTPPORT = 22;
        String SFTPUSER = "root";
        String SFTPPASS ="";
        String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "D:\\Upload";

        Session     session     = null;
        Channel     channel     = null;
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

        try{
                    JSch jsch = new JSch();
                    session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER,SFTPHOST,SFTPPORT);
                    session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
                    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
                    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                    session.setConfig(config);
                    session.connect();
                    channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
                    channel.connect();
                    channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
                    channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
                    File f = new File("trial.txt");
                    channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());
        }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        }

        }
```

Comment: do you have an SSH server running and listening on localhost already?

Comment: Yes I have installed ssh server on localhost.

Comment: have you tried to ssh localhost outside of this program?  If connection is refused then it would mean it can't connect to your ssh server.

Comment: Is SSH server enough for SSH2 as well ?

Comment: I'm sure it's using SSH2 by default.  If you get connection refused then that means it can't connect at all.  Can you "telnet localhost 22"?

Comment: telnet not recognised as an internal or external command

Comment: You can install telnet cliens. Windows contains Telnet Client component

Answer (score 0):

"Connection refused" means that there is no process listening for connections at the IP address and port which you're trying to connect to. In this case, the most likely explanation is that your SSH server process isn't running, or perhaps it has been configured to listen on some other port than port 22.

It looks like this is a Windows system? If that's the case, you could check the task manager to see if there is a copy of the `sshd` program running. To see if something is listening on port 22, open a command-line window and run `netstat -an`. Then look for a line like this:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:22            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
                 ^^-- Listening on port 22
```

If `sshd` isn't running, it needs to be started. If it is running, but nothing is listening on port 22, then you should examine sshd's configuration file.

If you need further help starting sshd, you should ask on https://superuser.com/.